# how to migrate from ionic3 to ionic2 and also from ionic2 back to ionic3

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I want to know how to exchange between ionic 3 and 2 or 2 to 3 with keep same project

im use WINDOWS. in the  first time, I install

```
npm install -g ionic Cordova
```

and for starting a new project i insert like following docs in [ionicframework.com](http://ionicframework.com) :

```
ionic start [myproject] blank
```

and

```
 cd [myproject]
 ionic serve
```

i don't know what the version ionic was installed? is the latest version by default or what?
because of this article here :
https://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/

tell should install v2 in the first time and then we want to move to 3 !!

and I want to know how can moving between the version 2>>3 or 3>>2 without any crash.
and I'm afraid if I'm using v3 by default and give something wrong while coding

plizzz someone explain carefully my issue

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to use a node version manager or nvm for short, which would let you handle different versions of node. By having different versions of node you can have ionic 3 on node X.X version and ionic 2 in a different one.

since you are using windows you can use this [one](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can type in your console 'ionic info' and then you will see all info from your project.
Sample output, from my environment:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 6.3.1 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.1.2 browser 4.1.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.0

System:

    Node       : v7.4.0
    OS         : Linux 4.4
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 5.0.3
```

You have to pay attention that there are differences between what is installed globally and what is local.
Globally you should have ionic-cli, which is the command line tool used to manage Ionics' project (either 1, 2, or 3).

The version of the framework you are using is the Ionic Framework, installed locally, and managed by npm (via package.json, the package is called 'ionic-framework').
So, do change dependencies, you should only change the package.json from your project.
You must pay attention, too, that each ionic-framework version has its own dependencies versions, specially from @angular (example: ionic-framework v2 uses angular2, ionic-framework v3 uses angular4).

Comment: ok thanks for your helpful comment my ionic info is here:
http://prntscr.com/ft0pix
i think i have something missing,like 
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0 and other thing is that normal ? or i need add something else